# Granting access to mailbox/calendar to another with MFA enabled?

Tags: email, multi-factor, outlook

Jane needs access to John's Outlook mailbox and calendar. When Jane attempts to access it (she has his UN & PW) John receives the MFA challenge preventing Jane from accessing it.

This works exactly as expected, problem is Jane is the admin assistant to John the CEO. Jane puts his schedule together in the evenings from home and is now locked-out of his account.

Any suggestions to safely share an O365 mailbox/calendar w/MFA enabled?